# AngularJS control over precise DOM rendered by directive

Tags: angularjs

I want to "directivize" search results. Each result will be rendered as a `li` within a `ul` HTML tag.

This means that I want to avoid the default AngularJS behavior of rendering to the DOM the containing directive element.

```
<ul>
  <my-result>
    <li></li>
  </my-result>
  <my-result>
    <li></li>
  </my-result>
</ul>
```

I have tried using `replace: true`, but this results in a `TypeError`:

> definition.match is not a function

Can someone point me in the right direction here? Perhaps I should use an attribute directive, but then I am unsure how to bind the isolate scope items?

My directive looks like this:

```
var template = require('text!./template.html');

return function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            select: '&',
            result: '=',
        },
        template: template,
    };
};
```

I am using an `ng-repeat` to render the results:

```
<ul>
  <my-result
    ng-repeat="result in results"
    result="result"
    select="select({result:result})"
  >
  </my-result>
</ul>
```

I am using Angular 1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replace option is deprecated. (since 1.3 I think?)

It would look better if your directive template included the `<ul>` element. In which case you wouldn't have the problem of seing the directive element between `<ul>` and `<li>`.

If you have no other option, as you said you can still use the directive as an attribute of the `<li>` like so:

```
<ul>
  <li my-result
    ng-repeat="result in results"
    result="result"
    select="select({result:result})"
  >
  </li>
</ul>
```

result and select should still be available to your directive's scope.

Comment: Can you hazard a guess as to why `ng-replace: true` results in a TypeError?

Comment: @BenAston I'd look into the 'select' attribute. I'm guessing you can't pass an argument there. Since you have access to result in the directive's scope, you can just run this.select(result) inside the directive's controller